# Wrong result from Matrix multiplication on GPU Mac Pro AMD OpenCL

Tags: python, gpu, opencl, pyopencl

Need help, I am trying to perform Matrix multiplication on my GPU using OpenCL. The results seem to very wrong but the dimension of the matrix is correct. I am not sure if there is some wrong pointer issue going on. Please help.

Tried on int and float(shouldn't matter) but both failed.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import datetime
import os
os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'

def openCL_multiplication(matrix1, matrix2):
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

    mf = cl.mem_flags
    a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=matrix1)
    b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=matrix2)
    dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, matrix1.nbytes )


    prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
        __kernel void multiplymatrices( int size, __global float * matrix1, __global float * matrix2, __global float * res) {

        int i = get_global_id(1); 
        int j = get_global_id(0);

        res[i + size * j] = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
            res[i + size * j] += matrix1[k + size * i] * matrix2[j + size * k];
        }

        }
        """).build()

    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Size:" + str(np.int32(len(matrix1))))
    print("a:" + str(a_buf))
    print("b:" + str(b_buf))
    prg.multiplymatrices(queue, matrix1.shape, None,np.int32(len(matrix1)) ,a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)

    final_matrix = np.empty_like(matrix1)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, final_matrix , dest_buf)

    print (final_matrix)


    delta_t = datetime.datetime.now() - t0
    print ('OpenCL Multiplication: ' + str(delta_t))

    return final_matrix


M1 = np.array([[2,3],[1,4]])
M2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(M1)
print(M2)



res = openCL_multiplication(M1, M2)
print(res)
```

Output is as below:
OpenCL Multiplication: 0:00:00.004049

[[                  0                   0]
 [4323174168305532928 4323174168305532928]]

Comment: More detailed output [[2 3]
 [1 4]]
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
Choose platform:
[0] <pyopencl.Platform 'Apple' at 0x7f8c8bd95ea0>
Choice [0]:0
Choose device(s):
[0] <pyopencl.Device 'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 v2 @ 3.70GHz' on 'Apple' 
[1] <pyopencl.Device 'AMD Radeon HD - FirePro D300 Compute Engine' on 'Apple' 
[2] <pyopencl.Device 'AMD Radeon HD - FirePro D300 Compute Engine' on 'Apple' 
Choice, comma-separated [0]:1
Size:2
OpenCL Multiplication: 0:00:00.004049
[[                  0                   0]
 [4323174168305532928 4323174168305532928]]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know anything about python or pyopencl, but your OpenCL kernel code looks OK. (Although I'd accumulate the result in a private variable and only write to `res[i + size * j]` once at the end; this will be much more efficient but the code should provide correct results as it stands.)

`4323174168305532928` is `0x3BFF00003BFF0000`, which at first glance looks to me like the binary representation of 2 32-bit floats back-to-back. So I suspect your kernel is fine but your handling of the buffers is incorrect - you're interpreting them as the wrong data types, 64-bit integers instead of floats. This is going to be pyopencl/python specific so I can't tell you the correct answer, but hopefully this puts you on the right track for working it out yourself, or perhaps someone else can chip in.